# Why is it termed heap sort is best for external sorting?

Tags: sorting, heapsort, binary-heap, external-sorting

While studying sorting algorithms, it is referred to as heap sort is used for external sorting.
I am not able to figure out how does it differ in terms of sorting techniques when we deal with the external storage? Or What is that something which heap sort does uniquely to be considered useful for external sort?

Could someone explain this?

Comment: That's not heapsort. That's mergesort with a heap-based k-way merge.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example from [the Linux kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/lib/sort.c#L46):

> This function does a heapsort on the given array. Sorting time is O(n log n) both on average and worst-case. While qsort is about 20% faster on average, it suffers from exploitable O(n*n) worst-case behavior and extra memory requirements that make it less suitable for kernel use.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Comparison_with_other_sorts):

> Heapsort also competes with merge sort, which has the same time bounds. Merge sort requires Ω(n) auxiliary space, but heapsort requires only a constant amount. Heapsort typically runs faster in practice on machines with small or slow data caches, and does not require as much external memory.

Comment: So you mean to say, since heap doesn't use additional auxiliary memory unlike its competitor (having similar asymptotic running time) sorting algorithms - MegeSort and QuickSort, it is faster when sorting items stored on external storage, right?

Comment: The limited space requirements make it more practical for working with very large sets.  In real-world use cases that can make it faster (e.g. staying in cache).  Also when dealing with external sorting you probably don't want to hit the worst case scenario of a quicksort, which would be far slower.

Answer (score 1):

The external part of the sort is k-way merge sort. Blocks or files of data on external media, such as hard drive(s) are repeated merged "k" at a time until a single sorted file is produced.

A min-heap is a common way to implement the internal portion of a k-way merge.

The initial pass to create the blocks or files of data could be just about any internal sort, one that is stable if stability is needed. In the case of sorting records, merge sort can be used to sort an array of pointers to the records, which reduces the space requirement since only the array of pointers requires a second array, as opposed to a second array for the records. It should be noted that sorting the pointers can be slower than sorting records, since sorting via pointers ends up random accessing records for compares, which isn't cache friendly.

Gnu sort for large text files is an example of an external sort. It reads a "chunk" of lines at a time, creating pointers to the lines, and uses merge sort on the pointers, then creates a temporary file for each chunk sorted. It then does a 16-way (16 is the default) merge on the temporary files until it reaches the final merge step where the final merge goes to the specified output file.

Link to source. It's a big program, partially because it has so many options.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c

Answer (score 0):

Not

> *heap sort* is best for creation of *initial run*s in *external sorting*,

but *using a heap to create the initial runs* leads to an *expected* initial run *length* twice the size of the heap (for a uniform distribution of keys), consequently, to half as many initial runs as any method sorting each batch of records and writing it as a run (using the same amount of RAM).
With two-way merging, half as many initial runs saves an entire pass. With advanced merging schemes, a high degree (number of runs merged into one), or even number of passes (ratio data/RAM size), this loses impact.